# How to declare a member in a base template class where the type is dependent of the derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, crtp, abstract-base-class

Given a base class using CRTP,  I'm looking at declaring a member in the base template class where the type is dependent of the derived class.

While the following works as intended:

```
template <class T> class BaseTraits;
template <class T> class Base {
    using TypeId = typename BaseTraits<T>::TypeId;
    TypeId id;
 public:
    Base() { id = 123; }
    TypeId getId() { return id; }
};

class Derived;
template <> class BaseTraits<Derived> {
public:
    using TypeId = int;
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
     Derived foo;
     return foo.getId();
}
```

I wonder if I could simplify the implementation.  I could add a second template parameter to the `Base` template, and make `BaseTraits` simpler or even get rid of it.  However the above snippet is already an attempt to remove the  second template parameter.  I'm looking at solutions that doesn't involve a second template parameter for `Base`.

I've tried something like the following but it doesn't compile:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Derived'

```
template <class T> class Base {
    using TypeId = typename T::TypeId;
    TypeId id;
 public:
    Base() { id = 123; }
    TypeId getId() { return id; }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
    using TypeId = int;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
     Derived foo;
     return foo.getId();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

- I'm limited to c++14.
- `Base` must be a template.
- Performance is a must.

Comment: Well your second example doesn't work because you can't use the class as template parameter before it was even fully declared. What do you want to achieve with those classe? Are you sure that they need to be templated at all?

Comment: @MarošBeťko You very much can, it's an incomplete class at this point and you can use an incomplete class as a template parameter.

Comment: @MarošBeťko  I'd like Base to declare a member that only Derived know the type.  Yes I need to use templates, at least for Base.

Comment: Do you really need `id` to be a member of `Base`? You could make it a member of `Derived` just as well...

Comment: Unfortunately yes.  In fact I need an array of those.

Comment: It isn't clear why you strictly need it there. You can have a function that returns (a reference/pointer to) the id array in Base, while the array itself sits in Derived.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible to make a member type *directly* dependent on the derived class? Taking appart the result type of a member function declared with `auto` (deduced return type), *it is not possible.*

So the use of a *type-trait* as you do in **your solution is the best and only solution**.

The reason is that a base class must be a complete type when the derived class is defined: the compiler must first instantiate and parse the base class definition before it parses the derived class definition, [C++ standard N4140 [derived.class]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.derived#2) (bold is mine):

> The type denoted by a base-type-specifier shall be a class type that is **not an incompletely defined class**;[...]

Comment: Have you noticed this meaningless double negation "*not* an *in*completely"!

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename TypeId> class Base 
{
private:
    TypeId id;
public:
    Base() { id = 123; }
    TypeId getId() {return id;}
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived, int> {};
```

Comment: Thank you @killzone-kid.  Yes it would be simpler however I'm looking at solutions that doesn't involve a second template parameter for Base.  In fact this what I have today.  My goal is to reduce the number of template parameters for Base to just one.

Comment: As you can see first param is not used here, I left it because you had it originally and I thought you might need it later. You can just `template <typename TypeId> class Base` and `class Derived : public Base<int> {};` if you want to.

Comment: I extracted the gist of the real code to focus on the problem.  Derived needs to inherit from Base.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of simplified, but you pay some price for it.

```
#include <any>

template <class T> class Base {
    std::any id; // expensive, but cannot have T::TypeId here
 public:
    Base() : id(123) {}
    auto getId() { 
         return std::any_cast<typename T::TypeId>(id); 
    } // T::TypeId is OK inside a member function
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
    using TypeId = int;
};
```

Comment: Thank you @n.m.  Your solution is good however I can't use std::any because I'm limited to c++14 in my current environment and this is a performance critical application.

Comment: You can write your own simplified `any` or use `boost::any` (or just use `void*` in a pinch), but performance is going to suffer in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not reversing the class hierarchy?

```
template <class T>
class Base : T {
    using TypeId = typename T::TypeId;
    TypeId id;
 public:
    Base() { id = 123; }
    TypeId getId() { return id; }
};

struct BasicDerived {
    using TypeId = int;
};


using Derived = Base<BasicDerived>;
```

Comment: I'm not sure to follow.  Derived needs to be a children class of Base using the CRTP.

Comment: @Flyer yeah, it's no longer CRTP. Derived is now the base class, and Base is now the derived class.

Comment: I have multiple Derived classes.  Base must stay the parent class.  That was an interesting thinking though :)

Comment: @Flyer if you need Base to stay the parent class, this won't apply indeed.

Comment: @Flyer I suggest you to check the cppcon 2017 talk "Agent Based class design". It's about composing the interface and implementation of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I thought some more... this isn't too unpleasant:
You could have a binding struct, could even be written as a macro, declared just before the real class.
The binding struct defines the enum and an incomplete typedef to the real class.
The template is defined before all of that, but uses typename to defer its dependency, but it is instanced by the real class and only dependant on the binding struct

```
template <class ThatClassWrapper>
class MyBase
{
protected:
    typedef typename ThatClassWrapper::TypeId TypeId;
    typedef typename ThatClassWrapper::RealClass ThatClass;
    TypeId typeIdValue;
    TypeId  GetTypeId() {   return typeIdValue; }
    std::vector<ThatClass*> storage;
};

class SomeClass;
namespace TypeIdBinding
{
    struct SomeClass
    {
        enum TypeId
        {
            hello, world
        };
        typedef ::SomeClass RealClass;
    };
}
class SomeClass: public MyBase<TypeIdBinding::SomeClass>
{
public:
    bool CheckValue(TypeId id)
    {   return id == typeIdValue;   }
};
```

Note that the real class is using TypeId as defined in the template base, and the named members are not directly visible. You could fix that by having the template Base derive from the binding struct (confirmed that it compiles that way). though I actually like that in c++11 you can export or typedef just the enum typename from another namespace and use that type name as a prefix for the enum members, helping to avoid name pollution.

Comment: Thank you for this other suggestion.  You are very creative :) I I agree with that it isn't too unpleasant but it is not CRTP anymore and it looses the Derived > Base inheritance.  As you said it seems like I've hit the wall of circular dependencies and I think @oliv is right.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you have hit the wall of hard circular dependencies.
Any way out will be smelly.
Two template arguments seems like a small price in the end.

Could you declare a dummy template class that takes Derived and TypeID? I don't think it gains you anything, though.

Is TypeID:Derived a 1:1 mapping? Would it feel better to over-represent that 1:1 mapping with another helper template to back-look-up Derived from TypeID? Note that TypeID would need to be defined outside the Derived class to do this.
Does TypeID really need to be defined inside the class? Could it leach off the passed-in definition in Base to support the existing use of the internal typedef?

Can you double-include? Split or macriose your definition of derived so that typeid is in a base class definition that can be included before the template? This DerivedBase could be declared in a namespace and contain a typedef link back to the full Derived class so Base can find it for references.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Indeed I might keep the second template parameter.

"Is TypeID:Derived a 1:1 mapping?"  Yes

"Would it feel better to over-represent that 1:1 mapping with another helper template to back-look-up Derived from TypeID?"   Do you mean like the BaseTraits template does ?   I don't know.  It doesn't seems much simpler than the second template parameter.

"Does TypeID really need to be defined inside the class?" No.  I don't understand the follow up question.

"Double-include or split ?"  That's interesting.  What do you mean by typedef link back though ?